# MediaStreamTrack stop method not working. is it deprecated?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, webcam

I have following code that was working fine but eventually it stopped working.

I think that track.stop() method is deprecated. If is it so then what are the alternatives.

```
function stopCam() {
localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    track.stop();
});
}
```

Comment: No, the `stop` method had not been deprecated. You have a bug elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, It was my bug. I was cloning the track for other use and not stopping that stream.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all the stream that cloned through main stream. Only stopping the main stream does not stop all the stream. We have stop it all else webcam still runs in browser.